# Is using defvar for a non-global variable ok?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am calling `defvar` in the middle of a function definition. And so far I've always seen its use, with `defparameter` for global variable. Like `*error-output*` or `*standard-output*`.

```
(defun consume-socket-reply (socket end-test-form)
  (do* ((line "" (read-line (usocket:socket-stream socket) nil))
        (text "" (concatenate 'string text line)))
       ((funcall end-test-form) text)))

(defun read-http-content (socket)
  (defvar line)
  (consume-socket-reply socket (lambda () (not line))))
```

Is there a better way to write what I am trying to do? That is: being able to pass the end-test-form to the final inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've modified my code that way, and removed the call to `defvar`:

```
(defun consume-socket-reply (socket end-test-form)
  (do* ((line (read-line (usocket:socket-stream socket) nil)
              (read-line (usocket:socket-stream socket) nil))
        (text line (concatenate 'string text line)))
       ((funcall end-test-form line) text)))

(defun read-http-header (socket)
  (consume-socket-reply socket (lambda (line) (equal line ""))))

(defun read-http-content (socket)
  (consume-socket-reply socket (lambda (line) (not line))))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Defvar` always creates a globally special variable (unless it already exists, of course).  It does not matter where you call it.

It is usually used as a toplevel form or directly inside of an `eval-when`.  The only reason to put it anywhere else that I can think of is the use of closures.

In all other cases, I would strongly suspect that the code does not mean what the author thinks it does.

Here, the globally special variable `line` is created on the first call of `read-http-content`.  This may lead to surprising effects if you use the name `line` in other places.  Don't do that.